# iOS 6 Social integration - go to settings issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I'm trying to integrate Facebook sharing procedure into my app. I'm using `UIActivityViewController` like this:

```
NSArray * activityItems = @[self.imgView.image, self.txtField.text];
UIActivityViewController * activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Till now all have been working fine. But I've met such problem - when I click on facebook icon and enter the facebook sharing screen the alertView appears:

[image]

so the problem is - when I click Setting my controller is just dismissed and nothing happens. For twitter all is working well - when Settings button is clicked my app is going background and the Settings is opened. Why this does not work for Facebook? Any help will be appriciated.

ADDED:
Using SLComposeViewController leads to the same behavior - Settings does not open

Comment: As I know openURL doesn't work for the settings anymore. Where's your exact problem? The settings or facebook?

Comment: it DOES work with twitter! Yeah my problem is that user can't be redirected to Settings automatically as it is done in twitter dialog.

Comment: I've not checked on a phone, but I have the same problem on the simulator.

Comment: I have the same problem in Twitter. Clicking on settings closes it and does nothing. Using self presentViewController:tweetSheet

Comment: hehe, strange thing...I have it working fine with tw

Comment: Having the same problem with iOS 6.1 simulator. Works with Twitter, but not with Facebook.

Comment: How can this be a problem when neither facebook or twitter icons will show in UIActivityViewController if you're not logged in (devices).

Comment: Am getting same problem in IOS 7 .so how can i solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug seems to be fixed in new version of iOS (6.0.1) At least I have all working well since my last updgrade.

Answer (score 2):

iOS 6.0.1 resolve this issue. Update software on device it go setting view.

Comment: Am getting same issue in IOS 7.how can i solve this issue in IOS 7

Answer (score 2):

i am having the same issue  you update the ios from 6 to 6.0.1 and remove the verification type `**SLServiceTypeFacebook**` in `**SLComposeViewController**` at first.,thats all working fine for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I just integrated the facebook social framework into my app and had exact same issue on iOS 6.1, i.e. when my facebook account is not setup, I will get this warning, but clicking "Setting" will simply dismiss the dialog instead of bringing me to the device's setting page.

I found out this seems to be a simulator ONLY issue, it works perfectly on real device. I'd suggest you to give a try.