# How to go facebook setting page of the Iphone On click of setting button in alert view IOS6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS 6 Social integration - go to settings issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638132/ios-6-social-integration-go-to-settings-issue)

I'm using IOS 6 sharing feature of twitter and facebook. If i didn't configured my accounts in the general setting of Iphone . Its giving me the alert view of settings. See attached screenshot.

I'm not able to attach screenshot as I'm new here

But when I click on settings button it wont take me to the setting page . How to do this ? please help

Comment: This shouldn't be happening. This alert, and corresponding settings button is a function automatically generated by iOS. There is nothing you have to do manually to make this work.

Comment: yeah thats generated automatically , But is there any way i can take user to the setting page . If user didn't configured his facebook or twitter account

Comment: Yeah its working fine with twitter Don't know whats the problem with Facebook ?

Comment: That's the thing that it's working with others and fails with FB..I don't know what's happening this might be some kind of FB bug I think