# <Error>: CGImageCreate: invalid image size: 0 x 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, cocoa-touch, slcomposeviewcontroller

> **Before give duplicate mark read my whole question:**

I know might be there is many question related to my title but issue is different.

I am using `Mac OS X 10.9.3` and Xcode `5.1.1`.

In my app I just want to share image, URL link and some description on Facebook and Twitter so I used `SLComposeViewController` and my code is below.

```
-(void)btnShareTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
  if(sender.tag == 100)
    [self shareProductContentOnTwitterORFB:@"Facebook"];
  else 
    [self shareProductContentOnTwitterORFB:@"Twitter"];   
}
```

Method body:

```
-(void) shareProductContentOnTwitterORFB:(NSString *) shareON
{
    SLComposeViewController *shareKit =  nil; // also tried with [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if([shareON isEqualToString:@"Twitter"])
        shareKit = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    else
        shareKit = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [shareKit setInitialText:@"My Description Text."];
    [shareKit addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"boston-shopping.jpg"]]; // I also tried with .png image
    [shareKit addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]];
    //[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:shareKit animated:YES completion:nil];
    [self presentViewController:shareKit animated:YES completion:nil]; /// I also tried with above comment.
}
```

After execute above code, `SLComposeViewController` will be open and in my console

```
<Error>: CGImageCreate: invalid image size: 0 x 0.
```

display only with **Facebook** and get exactly same problem [Look at this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638132/ios-6-social-integration-go-to-settings-issue)
I am sure my image is not `nil`, I was checked it.

Above question said -

> **This bug seems to be fixed in new version of iOS (6.0.1) At least I have all working well since my last updgrade.**

But I am testing on **iOS 6.1** still I am getting same issue and in **iOS 7.0 and 7.1** the error message in console *(`<Error>: CGImageCreate: invalid image size: 0 x 0.`)* Not display but I cam not able to go to on setting App in both **Facebook and Twitter**.
What is problem ? where I am wrong? Is this apple Bug ??
Please give your suggestion.

Comment: Can you give it just a try : declare `SLComposeViewController` as property and see.

Comment: @Maulik - Tried it, Not working for me :(

Comment: I would like to get your code :)

Comment: Just to be sure of how you responded to the comment above - you did make "SLComposeViewController *shareKit" either a strong ivar or a strong property? Usually bad form to not keep a strong reference to an object like this. Also, instead of one line "[shareKit addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"boston-shopping.jpg"]];" use a UIImage variable, set it to the image, then assert(image) or at least log it and see what you get.

Comment: @DavidH - I have tried with declare object of `SLComposeViewController` with `@property` but it does not work for me and also i tried with use of UIImage *image = [UImage... its not working :(

Comment: So try commenting out the line where you add the image - any change? Try putting a breakpoint on CGImageCreate() and see what the stack says. Failing that, build a small demo app that has the problem, put it on Dropbox, and offer a bounty for the proper fix.

Comment: a minimal project to reproduce the issue would help...

Comment: @iPatel Same issue aries in my project as my knowledge it's iOS Bug

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this stack trace after I called `[self presentViewController:shareKit animated:YES completion:nil];` :

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x199f3, 0x0026a871 CoreGraphics`CGPostError, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
  * frame #0: 0x0026a871 CoreGraphics`CGPostError
    frame #1: 0x0021bfc0 CoreGraphics`CGImageCreate + 296
    frame #2: 0x00458ea5 UIKit`_UICreateCGImageFromCARenderServerBuffer + 201
    frame #3: 0x007e7b0e UIKit`-[UISnapshotView captureSnapshotRect:fromView:withSnapshotType:] + 1712
    frame #4: 0x008fdfa7 UIKit`-[_UIRemoteViewController _snapshotAndRemoveTextEffectsRemoteView] + 337
    frame #5: 0x008fe064 UIKit`-[_UIRemoteViewController _applicationWillResignActive:] + 33
    frame #6: 0x00f9a4f9 Foundation`__57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 + 40
    frame #7: 0x014e50c5 CoreFoundation`___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 + 85
    frame #8: 0x0143fefa CoreFoundation`_CFXNotificationPost + 2122
    frame #9: 0x00ecebb2 Foundation`-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 98
    frame #10: 0x0041abb1 UIKit`-[UIApplication _deactivateForReason:notify:] + 381
    frame #11: 0x0041ac3d UIKit`-[UIApplication _deactivateForReason:] + 48
    frame #12: 0x0041cfd4 UIKit`_alertItemStateChanged + 73
    frame #13: 0x014e52e3 CoreFoundation`__CFNotificationCenterAddObserver_block_invoke_0 + 163
    frame #14: 0x014e53a0 CoreFoundation`____CFXNotificationPostToken_block_invoke_0 + 176
    frame #15: 0x0144a920 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
    frame #16: 0x0140dd31 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 257
    frame #17: 0x01431c51 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2273
    frame #18: 0x01430f44 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    frame #19: 0x01430e1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #20: 0x01dcb7e3 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 88
    frame #21: 0x01dcb668 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
    frame #22: 0x0041dffc UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1211
    frame #23: 0x00002f3d iostest`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff0d0) + 141 at main.m:16
```

I tried to run your code in my sample project and I found these :

- The error message was printed after `[self presentViewController:shareKit animated:YES completion:nil];` and before the modal `shareKit` view appeared.
- The error message was printed from `CGPostError` in `CoreGraphics`.
- I think this error occurred because of `-[UISnapshotView captureSnapshotRect:fromView:withSnapshotType:]`.
- I tried to comment out this line of yours, `[shareKit addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"boston-shopping.jpg"]];`, and I still got the error message. So, the error was not because of your code.

In my opinion, I think the error message you got was because of `UISnapshotView` was trying to take a snapshot of the current screen, but there was nothing there or there was some bugs in the method. So, it passed the wrong `width = 0 & height = 0` arguments to `CGImageCreate` that caused the error.

So, rest assured, this is not your bug. Just ignore it.

Answer (score -1):

Try and create the `CGImageRef` object yourself. You can replace the line:

```
[shareKit addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"boston-shopping.jpg"]];
```

with this:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"boston-shopping" ofType:@"jpg"];
CGDataProviderRef source = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename([filePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(source,
                                                        NULL,
                                                        true,
                                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
[shareKit addImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

Comment: I tried your code, its not working for me.. Same issue .. its might be bug of Apple still not solve.. :(

Comment: Every `UIImage` has a `CGImage` inside. This way you are just wasting data.

Comment: @Sulthan I don't understand your issue with this code. All I've done here is offer a way to manually create the `UIImage` object via a `CGImage`. There's no wastage here.

Comment: @GuyKogus How is that better than `+[UIImage imageNamed:]`? You do absolutely the same but `imageNamed:` shares memory between `UIImage` instances with the same name. There's your wasted memory.

Comment: The idea was to try and create the `CGImage` manually to see if the `UIImage` creation method was doing something wrong. You're right that it's wasted memory but that wasn't the point of this answer.